# does not work split on powershell

Tags: powershell

I have code, which split string to array. So can you help me, why this is doesn't work?

```
$var="test.1->test.2"
$arr=$var.Split("->")
$arr[0]#show correct: "test.1"
$arr[1]#doesn't show...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works. But it did split the string by "-" OR ">", so `$arr[1]` has empty string between "-" and ">", and "test.2" is in `$arr[2]`.

So you can either:

```
$var="test.1->test.2"
$arr=$var.Split("->")
write-host $arr[0]
write-host $arr[2]
```

or:

```
$var="test.1->test.2"
$arr=$var.Split("->") | select -First 1 -Last 1
write-host $arr[0]
write-host $arr[1]
```

or something like:

```
$var="test.1->test.2"
$arr= $($var -replace "->","#").Split("#") 
write-host $arr[0]
write-host $arr[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

The string `Split()` method takes an array of characters and splits the string on any character that is in the array. Powershell also has a `-split` operator that takes a delimiter. I think you probably wanted to use the `-split` operator here.

Here's the difference. The first splits at both the '-' and the '>', the second splits on the '->':

```
PS C:\> $var.Split("->")
test.1

test.2
PS C:\> $var -split "->"
test.1
test.2
```

Note that `split` takes a regular expression pattern rather than a simple string. While that is fine for this particular pattern other punctuation could provide problems requiring you to escape special characters in the pattern or use the SimpleMatch option:

```
PS C:\> "a[b" -split "[",0,"SimpleMatch"
a
b
```

Comment: For some reason this behaviour appears to differ when running powershell from Linux vs. Windows. Using `.Split()` in linux, the provided string will behave as a delimiter in it's entirety, where on windows it does it on every single character individually. Not sure if this is a bug, but it left me pulling my hair out why this was happening.